# In Oracle SQL , how do you select columns by ordinal position?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to study this database , and I want to look for column data based on its position , like so:

```
select * from V$RESERVED_WORDS where COLUMNS.FIRST like '%'
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I get this error:

```
select * from V$RESERVED_WORDS where COLUMNS.FIRST like "%"
Error at Command Line:10 Column:57
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "%": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I'm using Oracle SQL .  Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Which is it, `'%'` or `"%"`?

Comment: @hvd - Ok i will try that, maybe it's " "

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow the question.  Neither `columns` nor `first` nor `columns.first` is a column in `v$reserved_words`.  So what is it that you are trying to find in this view?

Comment: @JustinCave - OK then I'm confused about what i'm trying to do.

Comment: use All_Tab_Cols for column names in tables and their respective position `Select * from all_tab_cols where Owner = 'SCHEMANAME'`

Comment: Are you trying to say "show me all the rows from `v$reserved_words` where the first column in `v$reserved_words` is like '%'"?  If so, that is not something that the SQL language allows (nor is it something that makes a whole lot of sense).  In this case, the first column will always be `keyword` so why not just use that?  If you weren't guaranteed that the first column would always be the same (i.e. it is a user-defined view where the column order may change), it would make even less sense to depend on the order of columns particularly where different data types would behave differently.

Comment: @JustinCave - Thank you, that makes sense to me. I will use keyword and see

Answer (score 1):

You cant use ordinal, but you need to specify column name. Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM V$RESERVED_WORDS
WHERE KEYWORD LIKE '%';
```